# couldn't compile example programs of WinDev Mobile with Android sdk installed in my PC

Tags: android, windev

I have just installed WinDev Mobile 18 on a fresh PC.

The Os is Win7 32Bit.

When I open any of the Android Examples that ships with WinDev Mobile and compile them for Android Apk I keep getting this error:

```
System error message:
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

How to solve this problem?

TIA

Answer (score 2):

had a problem when I update WINDEV Mobile17 and 18 through *"WdAutomaticUpdate"*. In version 18, I updated the SDK Tools but did not work fine at all(couldn't detect the files). Therefore, I tried going back to review 21 plus added a little tweak which really worked.

- Follow these steps:

> I downloaded the package "tools_r21-windows" 
>   renamed the folder "C:\Program Files(x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools" and
>   unzipped the "tools_r21-windows"
>   download the "pack_us_82456"
>   unzipped the folder "C:\WinDev17\Programs

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: I am not able to find and download "pack_us_82456" Can you post the link please.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't remember the link...why don't you search with the name?

Comment: I searched the name but Google came up with nothing useful. What isit? A Patch or and Update?